# Como faço para listar todas as tabelas com seus respectivos bancos?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Eu gostaria de listar todas as tabelas do meu banco de dados que termina com um nome especifico e também todos meus bancos de dados que correspondem essas tabelas. Tentei fazer mas não me retorna nada.

## Query

```
SELECT da.name AS BANCOS,ta.name as TABELAS
FROM sys.schemas da join  sys.tables ta
on da.schema_id = ta.schema_id
where ta.name like '%attach'
group by da.name, ta.name
```

Comment: Kelvin eu fiz uma edição na sua pergunta que creio que ficou mais legível, poderia me indicar pela minha edição se é isso mesmo que você deseja? Digo porque se não for eu volto com a pergunta do jeito que estava!

Comment: Valeu Marconi é isso mesmo que queria perguntar :)

Comment: Que problemão em :)

Comment: já estou dias tentando achar uma solução e não consigo achar uma saída...quase estou ferrado hehhee

Comment: Kevin, A resposta do @Rodolpho Sa funcionou pra mim. Creio que é o que deseja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A seguinte `query`:

```
DECLARE @tabelas TABLE(nome_database SYSNAME,
                       nome_schema   SYSNAME,
                       nome_tabela   SYSNAME);
DECLARE @database SYSNAME;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE bases CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
  SELECT d.name
    FROM sys.databases d;
OPEN bases
FETCH NEXT FROM bases INTO @database
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @tabelas(nome_database,
                       nome_schema,
                       nome_tabela)
  EXEC('SELECT ''' + @database + ''',
               s.name,
               t.name
          FROM ' + @database + '.sys.tables t
               INNER JOIN ' + @database + '.sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
         WHERE t.name LIKE ''%cliente''');

  FETCH NEXT FROM bases INTO @database;
END;
CLOSE bases;
DEALLOCATE bases;

SELECT *
  FROM @tabelas;

-- Resumo
SELECT nome_database,
       count(1) AS quantidade
  FROM @tabelas t
 GROUP BY nome_database;
```

- Utiliza a tabela [`sys.database`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql) para percorrer em um [`cursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180169.aspx);
- Monta uma `query` dinâmica utilizando as tabelas [`sys.tables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187406.aspx) e [`sys.schemas`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/schemas-catalog-views-sys-schemas) na sintaxe `[NOME DA DATABASE].[NOME DO SCHEMA].[NOME DA TABELA]`;
- Insere em uma tabela variável no formado `nome_database`, `nome_schema` e `nome_tabela`.
- No final a `query` com `group by` mostra a quantidade de tabelas que corresponde ao filtro por `database`;

Comment: Sorack essa é  a melhor resposta e retornou mesmo as tabelas que terminam com "ATTACH".Muito Obrigado :)

Comment: Você falou que para montar uma query dinâmica deveria usar "sys.table, sys.schemas ect" fiquei com uma dúvida nesse script que vc passou.no momento que quero saber o total de linha de cada tabela usando "ROWS" como passarei então essa rows no declare?

Comment: De fato esta resposta está mais completa que a minha. Parabéns @Sorack !

Comment: entendi.Pois no caso queria listar todos os bancos com todas as tabelas com nomes especificas que terminam com"ATTACH" e no final listar o total de linha de cada banco.Eu consegui fazer mas saindo um pouco de jeito que vc fez.só que o único problema é que retorna tudo como se fosse muitas tabelas.enquanto quero juntar todos em uma tabela só.

Comment: aqui um exemplo se puder da uma olhada.tentei um UNION mas nada.
EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'select ''?''AS "BANCOs", s.name, t.name AS "TABELAS",max(si.rows) as "Numero de Coluna"
 from [?].sys.tables t inner join [?].sys.schemas s 
 on t.schema_id = s.schema_id  
 inner join [?].sys.partitions si on t.object_id  = si.object_id
 where t.name like "%ATTACH" group by s.name,t.name'

Comment: eu acabei de ver e fui testar e seguir o passo a passo para entender. Ja agradeço pelo sacrifico que você esta fazendo, se disponibilizando para me ajudar eu fico grato por isso mesmo. essa parte aqui: select *
  from @tabelas;

select nome_database
       count(1) as quantidade
  from @tabelas t
 group by nome_database; lista os bancos e total de linhas mas queria o total de linhas de cada tabelas

Comment: ai mudei para : select nome_tabela,
       count(1) as quantidade
  from @tabelas t
 group by nome_tabela;so que a quantidade retorna tudo 1.creio que deveria usar um max() mas quando passo max(rows) me da um erro no rows que passei como parâmetro.Desculpa atrapalhar e gastar seu tempo mas preciso de ajuda...

Comment: "No final a query com group by mostra a quantidade de tabelas que corresponde ao filtro por database;" Ta certo @Sorack obrigado por tudo mas achou que talvez não expliquei bem.se você poderia só mostrar como mostrar a quantidade  de linhas(que foi o que eu pedi) que corresponde ao filtro por tabelas ficarei grato amigo.é só disso que preciso pra fachar.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que você pode utilizar algo assim:

```
declare @BaseName varchar(100);
Declare @SelectTables varchar(1000);
--Primeiro obtenho em um cursor a lista dos banco de dados existentes
declare C_bases cursor for SELECT name FROM sys.databases;

--Abre o curosr
open C_bases;
-- Posiciona o cursor na primeira linha
FETCH NEXT FROM C_bases INTO @BaseName

-- Enquanto ainda tem linhas no cursor
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    --Imprimo o nome do banco 
    print @BaseName

    -- Monto o comando SQL que obtém a lista de tabelas da base onde o cursor esta posicionado
    -- Ex.: Na query abaixo eu listo as tabelas do banco [master] 
    -- SELECT * FROM [master].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    set @SelectTables = 'SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME  FROM [' + @BaseName+  '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE''';
    -- Executa o comando SQL gerado
    execute (@SelectTables);


  -- Posiciona o cursor na próxima linha ( ou próxima base no caso)
  FETCH NEXT FROM C_bases INTO @BaseName 
END   

--Fecha o cursor
CLOSE C_bases;  
--Desaloca o curosr
DEALLOCATE C_bases;
```

Abs.

Comment: Ao meu entender essa é a resposta correta, só faltou adicionar `AND TABLE_NAME like '%attach'`. Poderia explicar essa resposta @Rodolpho?

Comment: Eu não entendi o que cada linha faça...dá para você explicar um pouco o código?

Comment: Claro. O `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` lista as tabelas do banco onde a query esta sendo executada. Sendo assim eu fiz um loop em `sys.databases` para pegar o nome da base e montar dinamicamente o select e assim obter as informações o INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  de outo database, por exemplo: `SELECT * FROM [master].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'` .

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta e colocar uns comentários lá.

Comment: @RodolphoSa [edita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210290/edit) sua resposta e acrescenta as informações por favor

Comment: Feito! Se precisar de mais alguma coisa, só avisar.

Comment: @RodolphoSa sensasional sua resposta, ficou muito bom essa Query. Só achei bem complexo. +1

Comment: hehehe Valeu @Rodolpho a sua resposta é mesmo isso.Com os comentários me ajudou um pouco a entender mas é muito complexo.Mesmo assim obrigado a todos de poder tentar me ajudar. vcs são demais!

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui finalmente resolver esse problema que eu tinha.Achei uma solução especifica do que eu estava procurando.Decidi postar aqui,pois acho que isso poderia ajudar uma outra pessoa que pode precisar uma dia. :)

```
DECLARE @banco_nome nvarchar(MAX), @tabela_nome nvarchar(MAX)

DECLARE @banco_cursor CURSOR  
DECLARE @sqlstatement nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @count_sql nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @total int

DECLARE @RegistrosFotograficos TABLE
(
  DatabaseName nvarchar(max),
  TableName nvarchar(max),
  Total int
)

SET @banco_cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT name FROM sys.databases

OPEN @banco_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @banco_cursor INTO @banco_nome
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sqlstatement = 'DECLARE tabela_cursor CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM ' + @banco_nome + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%ATTACH'' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlstatement

    OPEN tabela_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tabela_cursor INTO @tabela_nome
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @count_sql = 'USE ' + @banco_nome + '; SELECT @total=COUNT(1) FROM ' + @tabela_nome;
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @count_sql, N'@total int OUTPUT', @total=@total OUTPUT

        INSERT INTO @RegistrosFotograficos (DatabaseName, TableName, Total) VALUES (@banco_nome, @tabela_nome, @total);

        FETCH NEXT FROM tabela_cursor INTO @tabela_nome
    END
    CLOSE tabela_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE tabela_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @banco_cursor INTO @banco_nome
END
CLOSE @banco_cursor;
DEALLOCATE @banco_cursor;

SELECT * FROM @RegistrosFotograficos
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma solução para mostrar qual banco esta a tabela pesquisada:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%attach'
```

Isso também poderá te auxiliar:

```
SELECT *
FROM sysobjects sobjects
WHERE sobjects.xtype = 'U' and  sobjects.name like '%attach'
```

Segue lista de xtype

```
AF: Aggregate function (CLR) 
C: CHECK constraint 
D: Default or DEFAULT constraint 
F: FOREIGN KEY constraint 
L: Log FN: Scalar function 
FS: Assembly (CLR) scalar-function 
FT: Assembly (CLR) table-valued function 
IF: In-lined table-function 
IT: Internal table 
P: Stored procedure 
PC: Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure 
PK: PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K) 
RF: Replication filter stored procedure 
S: System table SN: Synonym SQ: Service queue 
TA: Assembly (CLR) DML trigger 
TF: Table function 
TR: SQL DML Trigger 
TT: Table type 
U: User table 
UQ: UNIQUE constraint (type is K) 
V: View 
X: Extended stored procedure
```

Comment: Não creio que seja isso! Ele quer saber quais tabelas terminam com `attach`e em quais bancos estão essas tabelas.

Comment: Ajustei o codigo

Comment: Não funciona. A tabela `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` só mostra da `database` selecionada

Comment: Infelizmente não é isso Luiz que estou procurando.Creio que a minha pergunta não ficou clara.Eu quero listar todas as tabelas que pertence a todos os bancos do meu sql.Só que só quero os nomes dos bancos que com as respectivas tabelas que termine com "ATTACH" não sei se assim ficou mais claro.

Answer (score -1):

Tente algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases as db
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES as tb ON db.name=tb.TABLE_CATALOG AND TABLE_NAME like '%attach'
```

Comment: O INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES só mostra as tabelas de onde a query esta rodando e não de todas as bases existentes na instalação. Se não fosse isso sua query seria perfeita.

Comment: Não funciona. A tabela `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` só mostra da `database` selecionada

Comment: Infelizmente isso não funcionou pra mim.o que eu quero fazer na verdade é listar todas as tabelas de cada banco de dados que tem no meu sql.então não há como usar o "use databse" pois não é uma verificação para um banco de dados mas para todos de uma vez. Mas valeu por responder Eder :)

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar  SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: A query que você passou funciona mas nesse caso eu tenho que usar o "USE minhaDataBase" E retorna só o resultado desse banco selecionado.Gostaria de saber se não tem um jeito de  retornar para todos os meus bancos de uma vez só?